# Custom ListView Adapters for multiple TextViews

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on an app with multiple TextViews in a ListView, but I seem to have encountered a problem. The list does not appear to get modified.
I'm attachig my code now

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private List<CustomItem> myItem = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listView;
EditText edit;
Button insert;
String getText;
StringTokenizer st;
private String text1,text2;


List<CustomItem> customItem = new ArrayList<CustomItem>();
ArrayAdapter<CustomItem> adapter_List;
CompleteAdapter completeAdapter;
CustomItem obj;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    insert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    populate();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    completeAdapter = new CompleteAdapter(customItem, this);
    listView.setAdapter(completeAdapter);




}

private void populate() {
    customItem.add(new CustomItem("Testing","Application"));

}




public void addToList(View view) {
    getText = edit.getText().toString();
    st = new StringTokenizer(getText," ");
    text1 = st.nextToken().toString();
    text2 = st.nextToken().toString();
    MainActivity.this.customItem.add(new CustomItem(text1,text2));
    MainActivity.this.completeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

/*
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomItem> {
    private MyListAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_row,myItem);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView== null){
            itemView =       getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false);
        }
        CustomItem customItem = myItem.get(position);

        TextView t1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);




        t1.setText(customItem.getName());
        t2.setText(customItem.getAddress());





        return itemView;
    }

}*/


}
```

this is my adapter class

```
class CompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomItem>{


private List<CustomItem> items;
private Context context;

CompleteAdapter(List<CustomItem> items, Context context) {
    super (context,R.layout.item_row,items);
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public CustomItem getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v= convertView;
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

        TextView name_text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView address_text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.address);
        holder.nameView = name_text;
        holder.addView = address_text;
        v.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
        holder = (Holder)v.getTag();

    CustomItem custom = items.get(position);
    holder.nameView.setText(custom.getName());
    holder.addView.setText(custom.getAddress());

    return v;

}

private class Holder {
    public TextView nameView;
    public TextView addView;
}
}
```

This is my CustomIte.java

```
class CustomItem{
private String name;
private String address;

CustomItem(String name, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
} 
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}}
```

As you can see I've tried with 2 adapters with the same result. There is data contained in the Strings being passed, so I think the problem is with the adapter. (The ids of all the components are perfect) What changes should I make?

Answer (score 2):

Should change in your `Adapter`

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return 0;
 }

@Override
public CustomItem getItem(int position) {
return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return 0;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return items.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

 @Override
public CustomItem getItem(int position) {
return items.get(position);
}
```

Comment: I made the changes that you said, but now the app crashes as soon as it opens

Comment: Error is here
CompleteAdapter.getView(CompleteAdapter.java:51)
 TextView name_text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime﹕ in writeCrashedAppName

Comment: Do like  `v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your adapter which return a null view (v)

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return items.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

 @Override
public CustomItem getItem(int position) {
return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    Holder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView =LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

        TextView name_text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView address_text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.address);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.nameView = name_text;
        holder.addView = address_text;
        v.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
        holder = (Holder)v.getTag();

    CustomItem custom = items.get(position);
    holder.nameView.setText(custom.getName());
    holder.addView.setText(custom.getAddress());

    return convertView ;

}
```

Hop it helps ;)